# PostgreSQL and Codeigniter Sessions issues

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am trying to store the user data into database in PgSQL with Codeigniter as framework.

Now I created a table ci_sessions:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ci_sessions (
  session_id varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ip_address varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  last_activity int check (last_activity > 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  user_data text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
) ;

CREATE INDEX last_activity_idx ON ci_sessions (last_activity);
```

In my config.php these are my parameters:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

In mysql these were enough to store the userdata into database.

But for **PgSql** I am getting numbers of errors:

- session_id was unknow to the db driver asked me to change it to id
- user_agent was also unknown, so I had to remove it from database
- last_activity, was also unknown
- Similarly for the driver the user_data should be only data as field.

I had to do many changes for it to work, still when I did as it asked for it did not store information regarding the userdata such as browser, user agent etc.

My error looked like this :

> ```
> Severity: Warning
> ```
>
> Message: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "data" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "data" ^
>
> Filename: postgre/postgre_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 242
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\project\application\core\MY_Controller.php Line: 13
>   Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\project\application\libraries\Admin_Controller.php
>   Line: 10 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\project\application\controllers\admin\Dashboard.php
>   Line: 11 Function: __construct
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\project\index.php Line: 316 Function: require_once

Comment: Are you sure that session table is created correctly ? see this documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver.  You can see the table schema for session table for both mysql and posgresql.

Comment: Yes maybe i was using same mysql table for postgres, that created an error for me

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE "ci_sessions" (
    "id" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "ip_address" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "data" text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX "ci_sessions_timestamp" ON "ci_sessions" ("timestamp");
```

According at the online [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) this is the table that you need.